# Material Texfield with typescript Error - The TextField is a convenience wrapper. cant be all things to all people, API would grow out of control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using mui textfield in a typescript wrapper components and using some props.

```
const TextFieldWrapper = (props: InputProps) => {
    const {name, type, valid,touched, errorMessage, ...otherProps} = props; 
    
  return (
    <>
      <TextField name={name} type={type} variant= 'outlined' {...otherProps}/>
      {!valid && touched && <ErrorMessage>{errorMessage}</ErrorMessage>}
    </>
  );
}
```

On `<TextField>` tag I am getting this error "The TextField is a convenience wrapper for the most common cases (80%). It cannot be all things to all people, otherwise the API would grow out of control."

When I am removing the {...otherProps} form textfield tag, the error gets removed. But I want to keep {...otherProps}. How to I resolve this problem ?

I tried this but not working:

```
import  TextField  from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import ErrorMessage from '../ErrorMessage';
import { InputProps as TextFieldProps } from '../../../model';
import { InputProps as MuiInputProps } from 'material-ui/Input'



const TextFieldWrapper = (props: TextFieldProps) => {
    const {name, type, valid,touched, errorMessage, ...otherProps} = props; 

  return (
    <>
      <TextField name={name} type={type} variant= 'outlined'  
      InputProps={{
          inputComponent: (inputProps: MuiInputProps) => (
            <MaskedInput {...otherProps}  />
          ),
        }}/>
      {!valid && touched && <ErrorMessage>{errorMessage}</ErrorMessage>}
    </>
  );
}

export default TextFieldWrapper;
```

**Error**
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you forgot to add the actual error message. You can see it by hovering over the error

Comment: ^^Added........

Answer (score 0):

Changing a textfield from self closing to having both opening and closing tags, solved a problem for me. Give it a try , it is a quick fix, not an in depth solution.